# CommandText Property Has Not Been Initialized SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I just started seeing this error message recently.
The database I am running it on is on a personal database that I use to test things. Nobody has touched the server/database (I am 100% certain of this) other than me.

Code I am running:

```
use [_Testing_Only];
go
-----------------------------------
```

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is:
> ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized

Why am I seeing this error all of a sudden?

What can I do to make it go away?

Comment: This error is a .Net error meaning it's probably originating from whatever client tool you're using (Probably SSMS) and not from SQL Server itself.

Comment: Gotcha, I have been ignoring the SSMS recent updates, I'll update it then.

Answer (score 1):

This happen in SSMS when you execute a comment. In your case you added a comment after the "GO" which mean that the comment was executed by itself which is like executing the following code

```
-----------------------------------
```

This is extremely annoying.

Comment: You suggestion resolved my issue. Thank you for sharing your knowledge/experience. It indeed is annoying. Had I not seen your this post I would have no idea what is the cause of the error. My upvote.

Comment: You are welcome `:-)` I glad I could help a bit.